# POI Workbook Multithread

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to write to same workbook (HSSFWorkbook) in multi-thread environment?
The workbook is stored in a thread-safe collection which is shared by the threads.
Each thread works on a different sheet.

Comment: Does the POI documentation say outright that the library is thread-safe? (I.e. has intentionally been implemented to be.) If not, assume it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write to same workbook in multithreaded environment. But if you have made it thread-safe then at one time only one thread will be able to access it.

Comment: I didn't understand, I want to use one workbook, all threads will get a reference to this thread and write to it new sheets

Comment: @omrid can you show some code ? what you have tried till now ? may be then we will be able to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have multiple threads writing to the *same* workbook, certainly not for all cases. Multiple threads writing to their own workbooks is fine though

Answer (score 0):

The related entry in the [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224) describes this as follows:

> In short: *Handling different document-objects in different threads
>   will work. Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not
>   work.*
>
> This means the workbook/document/slideshow objects are not checked for
>   thread safety, but any globally held object like global caches or
>   other data structures are guarded against multi threaded access
>   accordingly.
>
> There have been discussions about accessing different Workbook-sheets
>   in different threads concurrently. While this may work to some degree,
>   it may lead to very hard to track errors as multi-threading issues
>   typically only manifest after long runtime when many threads are
>   active and the system is under high load, i.e. in production use! Also
>   it might break in future versions of Apache POI as we do not
>   specifically test using the library this way.

So you need to ensure only one thread works on one workbook object at the same time to be sure, e.g. by locking on the Workbook object itself.